# iPhone App Pick Up Sound

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am trying to do a certain action based on whether or not the user makes a loud sound.  I'm not trying to do any voice recognition or anything.  Just simply do an action based on whether the iPhone picks up a loud sound.

Any suggestions, tutorials, I can't find anything on the apple developer site.  I'm assuming i'm not looking or searching right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest thing for you do is to use the AudioQueue services.  Here's the manual:
[Apple AQ manual](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Basically, look for any example code that initialized things with AudioQueueNewInput().  Something like this:

```
    Status = AudioQueueNewInput(&_Description,
                                Audio_Input_Buffer_Ready,
                                self,
                                NULL,
                                NULL,
                                0,
                                &self->Queue);
```

Once you have that going, you can enable sound level metering with something like this:

```
// Turn on level metering (iOS 2.0 and later)
UInt32 on = 1;
AudioQueueSetProperty(self->Queue,kAudioQueueProperty_EnableLevelMetering,&on,sizeof(on));
```

You will have a callback routine that is invoked for each chunk of audio data.  In it, you can check the current meter levels with something like this:

```
//
//  Check metering levels and detect silence
//
AudioQueueLevelMeterState meters[1];
UInt32 dlen = sizeof(meters);
Status = AudioQueueGetProperty(_Queue,kAudioQueueProperty_CurrentLevelMeterDB,meters,&dlen);
if (Status == 0) {
    if (meters[0].mPeakPower > _threshold) {
        silence = 0.0;     // reset silence timer
    } else {
        silence += time;                
    }
}

//
//  Notify observers of incoming data.
//
if (delegate) {
    [delegate audioMeter:meters[0].mPeakPower duration:time];
    [delegate audioData:Buffer->mAudioData size:Buffer->mAudioDataByteSize];
}
```

Or, in your case, instead of silence you can detect if the decibel level is over a certain value for long enough.  Note that the decibel values you will see will range from about -70.0 for dead silence, up to 0.0db for very loud things.  On an exponential scale.  You'll have to play with it to see what values work for your particular application.

Comment: Thanks, this will help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has examples such as [Speak Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007802-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) which looks to have code relating to decibels. I would check some of the meter classes for examples. I have no audio programming experience but hopefully that will get you started while someone provides you with a better answer.

Comment: Hi @Joe. Can I use Speak Here in my project?

Comment: Hey @GajendraKChauhan, IANAL so I will refer you to the disclaimers in [the source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SpeakHere/Listings/AudioViews_AQLevelMeter_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007802-AudioViews_AQLevelMeter_h-DontLinkElementID_3). If you have questions consult a lawyer :) I wish I could be more helpful.