# Audio recording with audio level feedback in iOS

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, audio-recording, avaudiorecorder

I want to record audio on ios7 , I know I can do it using AVAudioRecorder but what i want is to create a visual feedback animation similar to the one attached in image. I want to know how to get the current audio input level and also how to create the required animation, I am new to animation.

Thanks
[image]

Comment: How to get sound decibels was already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183599/how-to-measure-noise-or-sound-and-displays-in-dba-in-iphone

Comment: @sangony thanks but its about playing not recording and i am also interested in knowing about animation thing

Comment: My bad. Take a look at this then. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436565/iphone-app-pick-up-sound

Comment: The animation part is beyond my skill set. Hopefully someone else can answer that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the EZAudio open source project. Has exactly what you are looking for.

https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio

Comment: Thanks a lot , I wrote my own stuff but I am sure this will help in future to me.